# C# Paste List<object> into Excel column withou looping

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I have some code that gathers issue from the application run and i wanted to create a report about issues. Unfortunately using `Intertop` makes this export a long run.

```
        //loop results
        int i = 2;
        foreach (EntryIssue entryIssue in DuplicatesList)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = entryIssue.dataString;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = entryIssue.fileLine;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = entryIssue.fileName;
            i++;
        }
```

There are three other sheets created and three other lists that fill them in code, but they work in similar manner.

Is there a way to avoid iteration of the list and paste the results from it in specific range?
I think this could save some time or should i use other library than `Intertop`?

EDIT:

Ok,
I had located a solution although it seems to work only on 2D arrays, there seems to be a problem with 1D array as it only assignes records based on first record within the array. I'm not sure how to solve that.

My initial idea was to paste it with `Linq`

1D arrays (doesn't work):

```
  xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range((object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1], (object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[DuplicatesList.Count + 1, 1]);
            var getArray = DuplicatesList.Select(r => r.dataString).ToArray();
            xlRange.Value = getArray;
            xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range((object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], (object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[DuplicatesList.Count + 1, 2]);
            getArray = DuplicatesList.Select(r => r.fileLine).ToArray();
            xlRange.Value = getArray;
            xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range((object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3], (object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[DuplicatesList.Count + 1, 3]);
            getArray = DuplicatesList.Select(r => r.fileName).ToArray();
            xlRange.Value = getArray;
```

Then i decided to iterate list elements into array, as i dont know if you can assign from list of objects into multidimensioarray.
On a file with 220 thousand items it went from above 10 minutes to approx 2-3 seconds.

2D array (does work)

```
        //set range
        xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range((object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1], (object)xlWorkSheet.Cells[DuplicatesList.Count + 1, 3]);
        //fill array 
        int i = 0;
        object[,] getArray = new object[DuplicatesList.Count, 3];
        foreach (EntryIssue entryIssue in DuplicatesList)
        {
            getArray[i, 0] = entryIssue.dataString;
            getArray[i, 1] = entryIssue.fileLine;
            getArray[i, 2] = entryIssue.fileName;
            i++;
        }
        //assign array to range
        xlRange.Value = getArray;
```

later on im clearing Marshall

```
    ips.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
    ips.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
    ips.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    ips.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: How many rows do you have? Iterating a list is normally quite fast.

Comment: collectively its from 30k to about 60k on each run, i had checked the time on creation of file etc. it's clearly slowing down on this loop, i find it quite strange but it seems that assigning data to worksheet is something that takes that time. When i tried simple assign to `var` rather than to worksheet it was almost Immediate end of run.

Comment: I guess there's a bit of background processing on these assignments. I wouldn't try any interop stuff here, that adds a lot of complexity and risk if you get the memory management wrong.

Comment: Check epplus on nuget. This way it would take ages to complete. You can also use ACE.OleDb and CopyFromRecordset or QueryTables.Add.

Comment: Just use 2D variant arrays, that's how Excel works.  If you only need one dimension, then just make the second dimensions length = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epplus from Nuget would be an easy solution. ie:

```
void Main()
{

    var r = new Random();
    var data = new List<MyData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        data.Add(new MyData { DataString = $"Data {i}", FileLine = r.Next(1, 1000), FileName = $"File #{i}" });
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("FromAnonymous");

    //Load the collection starting from cell A1...
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(data, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

    //...and save
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\AnonymousCollection.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        fi.Delete();
    }
    pck.SaveAs(fi);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

public class MyData
{
    public string DataString { get; set; }
    public int FileLine { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey, ill try it with other reports as im satisfied with performance while pasting data as range, although im wondering if you might have any tips about performance on Epplus and idea if there are any issues with memory leaks, i tried spire but it created massive memory leak. Normally with intertop application took 200 MB jumped to 600 MB during data collection and dropped to 200 MB after the run, with spire it went from 200 to 1,2 GB and dropped to 800 MB, didn't find a way to clean it. I wanted to use Spire to collect metadata but furtunately found another way.

Comment: Additionaly im accepting this answer as in fact epplus from my quick test does perform better than intertop.

Comment: To my experience, though Epplus is not the best always, it is certainly better than doing multiple interop calls (it is the worst). In some cases, my preference is interop, it can do more than what Epplus can but the things I am doing are done with few interop calls. Transferring data to excel, what is fastest are pasting from an array (2D), using ACE.OleDb and SQL, using CopyFromRecordset, using QueryTablesAdd and of course Epplus. Some of these require you to have a data source to connect to, if you can, probably QueryTables.Add is the fastest. Also for Pivot tables, there's PivotCaches.Add.